# Deserializing an object with an array is returning null with GSON, why?

Tags: java, gson

I have this result from server: 
`{"product_option_values":[{"id":43}, {"id":45}]}`

And, I Have these classes to parse the above string for the class below

```
public class MyClass {

    @Key("product_option_values")
    private List<ProductOptionValueResult> values;

    public List<ProductOptionValueResult> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<ProductOptionValueResult> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}

public class ProductOptionValueResult {

    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert the string above to an instance of MyClass like this:

```
MyClass myclass = gson.fromJson(stringAbove, MyClass.class);
```

However I get null in the object's values property, why?

Comment: I am not familiar with `@Key` - what library is it from?

Comment: Belongs to library ```GSON``` too. package ```com.google.api.client.util```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this annotation:

```
@Key("product_option_values")
```

You can use this one:

```
@SerializedName("product_option_values")
```

This is from `com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName`.